# How do I retrieve data that I have sent via a link?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble getting data from a link

How do I retrieve the data $row['review'] on the review.php page ?

```
<td align="left"><a href="review.php?id='. $row['review'] .  '"> Read Review </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `reviews.php`, you can do this:

```
$reviewID = $_GET['id'];
```

And to make sure it's set, I'd do the following:

```
$reviewID = ( isset($_GET['id'] ) : $_GET['id'] ? NULL;
```

**Explanation:**

The href value of your hyperlink would be similar to `review.php?id=XXX`. Query strings (as name/value pairs) is sent in the URL of a GET request. Since request method is `GET`, you'll need to use the `$_GET` super-global array and hence `$_POST` won't work.

You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` if you want to check the REQUEST type:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    //do something
}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: `is_null` is not necessary as `isset` checks that it exists and is NOT null.

Comment: `isset()` won't return *true* if the variable is null thus `is_null()`  is actually not necesary.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `$_GET` superglobal collection, it contains each querystring value.

```
$review = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: Should be `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: @user1829823: my answer *may* answer that question of yours.

Comment: @user1829823 The args in a URL after a `?` are part of the GET request

Answer (score 2):

It is **always** best to check if the GET variable exists before trying to grab it. To check that it is available and not null, you could can do this:

```
$__review_ID = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) array. To get the 'review' parameter, use:

```
echo $_GET['review'];
```

**EDIT**

To get the 'id' parameter:

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: Should be `$_GET['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

As PHP best practices you can use `filter_input`:

[PHP's new input_filter does not read $_GET or $_POST arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298535/phps-new-input-filter-does-not-read-get-or-post-arrays)

That's because you need sanitize passed by data to keep yor app secure from injection code, xss, etc...

```
FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED
FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT
FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
FILTER_SANITIZE_URL
```

I think this question is duplicated and need be closed.

Comment: Why another answers are valid, but as I said before: if best practice have any relevance, *maybe* this question is duplicated.

Comment: *I think this question is duplicated and need be closed.* -- I'm talking about that. If you think this question id duplicate, then say so in comments, and link to the duplicate. And if you have close-vote privilege, close-vote it. Saying it's duplicate and answering with unrelated information does not help.

Comment: If I'm sure the questioner understands the basic difference between getting a result of the variable in the global scope among sanitize the data, then I really think the question is duplicated. But as it seems the case of the OP can be beginner in PHP, my answer does not really apply to your case. BTW the scope of utilization makes all difference