# Accepting either '.' or ',' as decimal separators when using FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT?

Tags: php

I'm using the PHP filter_input function to parse an HTML form input. One of the input fields represents an amount of money. I expect that I will have some users using commas and some using dots as decimal separator. The FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT filter has a decimal option but I haven't figured out a clean way of accepting both characters as decimal separator.

Currently my code looks like the following line, but this doesn't accept amounts like `123.45`.

```
$money = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'money', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, array('options' => array('decimal' => ',')));
```

Is there any standard / clean way of accepting several types of decimal separator, without having to writing a custom parsing function?

Comment: Why not `$_POST['money'] = str_replace(".", ",", $_POST['money'])` on the line before?

Comment: Doing that does changes the value in the $_POST array but the filter_input call still returns false. My systems sends the user back to the form in case of validation error and fills it up with what the previously posted. With your idea, my system sends the user back to the form and changes his dot with a comma (which means that if he reposts the same data it would pass validation). I'm not sure why filter_input still fails even though I did a str_replace right before.

Comment: [It seems like modifying the superglobal array doesn't work well with filter_input.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298535/phps-new-input-filter-does-not-read-get-or-post-arrays) I'll try using filter_var instead.

Answer (score 5):

I rewrote my code using `filter_var` instead of `filter_input` and used  hd's `str_replace` trick. The end result looks something like:

```
$temp_money = str_replace(".", ",", $_POST['money']);
$money = filter_var($temp_money, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, array('options' => array('decimal' => ',')));
```

If `$_POST['money']` is null then `$money` will also be null, which is the same behavior as `filter_input`, so the rest of my validation code did not have to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$money = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'money', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) || filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'money', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, array('options' => array('decimal' => ',')));
```

Comment: This is the preferred solution. Clean and clear and self explanatory.