# PHP form request with javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

So i have a javascript that performs a simple form validation on

```
<form method="get" name="formPG" onsubmit="return (validateForm());" action="filter.php">
<p>Noun <input id="iNoun" name="fNoun" type="text" /></p>

<p><br />
Pronoun <input id="iPronoun" name="fPronoun" type="text" /></p>

<p><br />
Verb <input id="iVerb" name="fVerb" type="text" /></p>

<p><br />
Adverb <input id="iAdverb" name="fAdverb" type="text" /></p>

<p><br />
Adjective <input id="iAdjective" name="fAdjective" type="text" /></p>

<p><br />
Silly Word <input id="iSillyWord" name="fSillyWord" type="text" /></p>

<p><br />
Magic Spell <input id="iMagic" name="fMagic" type="text" /></p>

<p><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

The javascript says "hey this is filled in" or "hey this isn't filled in, please fill this in".

Now, I have a PHP file that collects the information from the HTML tags

```
<?php
    require "start.php"
?>

<div class="work"><</div>
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['fNoun']) && !empty($_GET['fPronoun']) && !empty($_GET['fVerb']) && !empty($_GET['fAdverb']) && !empty($_GET['fAdjective']) && !empty($_GET['fSillyWord']) && !empty($_GET['fMagic']))
{
    $noun = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'fNoun', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pronoun = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'fPronoun', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $verb = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'fVerb', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $adverb = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'fAdverb', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $adjective = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'fAdjective', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $sillyword = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'fSillyWord', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $magic = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'fMagic', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        echo "There was once a $adjective magician who roamed the wild terrains of $adverb <br>The magician $noun cast the mighty spell $magic around the $sillyword <br>$pronoun knew there was only one way to win the war - $verb";
}
else
{
    echo "parameters not provided."
}
?>

<?php
    require "end.php"
?>
```

The problem I am running into is it collects the information (which you can see it in the URL) however, it doesn't echo out the information to the screen.

Could it be a weird interaction with PHP and JavaScript?

Comment: Hi.  You should probably try running this without the functions to start and see if your data gets printed.  Also, depending on your settings you might have to declare the value a string    $b = (string)filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'b');

Comment: Okay, let me try this... I will edit this comment to the result
Result: blank page still
`filter.php?fNoun=q&fPronoun=q&fVerb=q&fAdverb=q&fAdjective=q&fSillyWord=q&fMagic=q` this is what is being passed

Comment: See previous comment and I think you may need to use filter_var as I believe filter_input is scalar refer to this  SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298535/phps-new-input-filter-does-not-read-get-or-post-arrays

Comment: I am looking at the debugger, i'm getting a 500 internal server error
`[Sun Apr 23 14:51:50.552397 2017] [:error] [pid 26426] [client 199.249.223.60:62465] File does not exist: /home/gyqynpkr/public_html/index.php`

Comment: Are you sending to filter.php? Check spellings of everything.  And here is an  example of what you're looking for I think... https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_sanitize_string  good luck

Comment: Yes i am passing to the php file. I believe that's the syntax i already have for my php script.

Comment: Is your form really submitting to filter.php? Because your error suggests it is going to index.php, unless that is an unrelated error.

Comment: it actually turned out to be an unrelated error that has nothing to do with anything. It was also sending to wp-login.php.... which is a script for Word Press and no where was i even referencing wordpress. The error turned out to be a reference to the script in the html doc was present so it was removed and then there was a missing semicolon in the php script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option, you will want to first check what filter_input returns and then you can assign that to a variable and display it, below is a simple example, derived from what w3schools provides here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_filter_input . The example below validates an email from a form and if filter input does not return false it will print a message saying 'This email:  is a valid Email'

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="get" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_GET["email"])) {
    if (!filter_input(INPUT_GET, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $email = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        echo("This email: ".$email." is a valid Email");
    } else {
        echo("Email is not valid");
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.